# How to edit a large shapefile in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

I need to add an ID field to a shapefile with 16,171,000 points (yes, a lot of points).

I try with QGIS' field calculator using `$id` and `$rownum`but this is my fifth day waiting for some results.

How can I do this faster?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Rather than doing it on Attribute Table (usual way), how about adding `ID ($id)` field on `Layer Properties | Fields (tab)`?

There you can find `Toggle editing` and `Field Calculator`; they work in the same way on the Attribute Table.

Comment: Thanks!! Works for me!! Takes for me 20 minutes more or less

Comment: @IvánCastilloOyarce +1 for Kazuhito's method. In addition to it, I suggest deactivating the layer from the Layers Panel before editing it (i.e. disable the visibility for that layer).

Comment: If you want to do further operations in your attribute table, I suggest to move away from using shapefiles. You can easily convert it into a spatialite/sqlite database and do the operations in the DB-Manager, if you know some basic SQL. This works usually much much faster.

Comment: Great, thanks @IvánCastilloOyarce . (And to mgri and AndreasK, too, for tricks I definitely learn).

Answer (score -2):

You can use attribute table of the shapefile then add an ID column or change the ID.

```
> Right Click on Shapefile in Layers Panel> Open Attribute Table
> In Edit mode (Ctrl + E) there will be a create New Field Icon (Ctrl+W)
> use that to create your ID field or edit existing fields.
```