# Calculate length of huge vector lines dataset

Tags: qgis, vector, line, length, big-data

I have a MultiLineString vector layer from which I would like to calculate the length.

[image]

I have tried to calculate the length with the Field Calculator by putting in the expression $length. The problem is that the dataset is very big (the attribute table consists of about 700,000 features) and my computer or QGIS is not capable of calculating that (at least when using this approach).

Any suggestions of other ways QGIS might be able to calculate the length and deal with the size of the data given the large number of features?

Comment: Are you trying to calculate the total length of lines in the layer, or the length for each line in the layer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Field calculator can be activated from `Layer Properties` window. It is on `Fields` tab (2.18) or `Source Fields` tab (3.0/3.2), which calculation is much faster than the one activated from the attribute table.

Comment: Interesting - do you have a reference for this, or have you tested it?

Comment: @Kazuhito is right. All operations made from the `Source Fields` tab are very fast. Here is a [good example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C9jx7Qry0FA).

Comment: Select part of roads with freehand select tool and calculate length for selected, and do it again and again...

Comment: Yes @Simbamangu I think [How to edit a large shapefile in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/245935/84455) was successful case.

Comment: Right, the OP there indicated that the process never completed using (I assume) the calculator in attribute table view, but it succeeded in 20m using the `Layer Properties` tab. Great, but there's no indication that OP's original method wasn't simply *hanging*. Can you provide any measured speed comparison between the two methods where it's known that the processes complete? I think your answer's good here but some more info would be worthwhile.

Comment: @Kazuhito it worked for me. Unfortunately QGIS was not able to save the attribute table after the calculation, so I just saved it as a .txt file.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Lasse Thanks, and I am sorry about the trouble to save the file. I think I saw similar issue while working in the latest QGIS 3.2 (not sure...) Is it possible for you to try QGIS 2.18, if you were also using 3.2?

Comment: @Simbamangu You are absolutely right, and it is sensible advice. Only problem I have is how to reproduce a sample which gives result. I mean, my Celeron laptop  quickly killed by big data (during `attribute table` test), while smaller dataset is not enough to measure the turn-around time (in `layer properties` test) because it finishes almost instantly...

Comment: Testing this in QGIS 3.2 with point files in a geopackage. For attribute table edit, @1k points (instantaneous), 10k (instantaneous), 100k (hangs application!). With 100k but using field calc from either main toolbar or the properties dialog, is also near-instantaneous. Somewhere along the way the table view calc breaks QGIS.

Answer (score 3):

One approach would be to split your line feature layer into multiple chunks, calculate the length for lines in each, then merge the split layer.

For example, you can clip your roads to individual polygons in an a shapefile of administrative boundaries (counties in the example below). Select from the menu Vector -> Geoprocessing tools -> Clip, and enable iterate over this layer option (green arrow button, circled below).

[image]

Alternatively, you could use Select by Location to select line features that intersect individual polygon boundaries. This may be desireable if you don't wish to split line features at administrative boundaries (i.e., if you want total length of lines that may fall in multiple polygons). Then run the $length calculation for selected subsets of the line layer.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For such number of data, Qgis may hang while trying to calculate the length. If the roads are of different categories, I would suggest you calculate by the categories after which you merge the table results to have your data as whole. You can as well categorize by any other attribute feature that differentiates the roads, run each category separately and finally merge or join  results.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know the total length and some other statistics use the "Show statistical summary" tool. It has letter Sigma as an icon in the main toolbar.

[image]